# vector sort and erase won't work

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, erase

When using this code to remove duplicates I get invalid operands to binary expression errors. I think that this is down to using a vector of a struct but I am not sure I have Googled my question and I get this code over and over again which suggests that this code is right but it isn't working for me.

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
fileSize = textFile.size();
vector<wordFrequency> words (fileSize);
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= fileSize - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < fileSize - 1; j++)
    {
        if(string::npos != textFile[i].find(textFile[j]))
        {
            words[i].Word = textFile[i];
            words[i].Times = index++;
        }
    }
    index = 0;
}

sort(words.begin(), words.end());
words.erase(unique(words.begin(), words.end(), words.end()));
```

Comment: Have you defined `operator<` for the items in the vector?

Comment: *Please* don't make us guess what the type of `vec` is. Please create the shortest **complete** program that demonstrates your error and post that into your question. http://sscce.org

Comment: @Rob i have added the smallest bit of my program i can.

Comment: @bobthemac: it's small (great) but it's also incomplete. What is `wordFrequency` what does `bool operator<(wordFrequency const&, wordFrequency const&)` looks like ? We cannot give meaningful answers with half questions. Oh, and what is the *exact* error message ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. `wordFrequency` is a structure consisting of a string and an int, and i don't have a `bool operator<(wordFrequency const&, wordFrequency const&)` because sites examples didn't show them so i didn't know about it.

Comment: Please don't introduce an `operator<` for sake of a single sort. Only introduce it if it makes real sense for the type.

Comment: Note also [you are using `unique` wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9621670/76722).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First problem.

#### `unique` used wrongly

```
unique(words.begin(), words.end(), words.end()));
```

You are calling the three operand form of `unique`, which takes a start, an end, and a predicate. The compiler will pass `words.end()` as the predicate, and the function expects that to be your comparison functor. Obviously, it isn't one, and you enter the happy world of C++ error messages.

### Second problem.

#### either use the predicate form or define an ordering

See the definitions of [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

You can either provide a

```
bool operator< (wordFrequency const &lhs, wordFrequency const &rhs)
{
    return lhs.val_ < rhs.val_;
}
```

, but only do this if a `less-than` operation makes sense for that type, i.e. if there is a natural ordering, and if it's not just arbitrary (maybe you want other sort orders in the future?).

In the general case, use the predicate forms for sorting:

```
auto pred = [](wordFrequency const &lhs, wordFrequency const &rhs)
{
    return lhs.foo < rhs.foo;
};

sort (words.begin(), words.end(), pred);
words.erase (unique (words.begin(), words.end(), pred));
```

If you can't C++11, write a functor:

```
struct FreqAscending { // should make it adaptible with std::binary_function
    bool operator() (wordFrequency const &lhs, wordFrequency const &rhs) const
    { ... };
};
```

I guess in your case ("frequency of words"), `operator<`makes sense.

Also note [vector::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase): This will remove the element indicated by the passed iterator. **But**, see also [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), `unique` returns an iterator to the new end of the range, and I am not sure if you really want to remove the new end of the range. Is this what you mean?

```
words.erase (words.begin(),
             unique (words.begin(), words.end(), pred));
```

### Third problem.

#### If you only need top ten, don't `sort`

C++ comes with different sorting algorithms ([based on this](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html)). For top 10, you can use:

- [`nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element): gives you the top elements without sorting them
- [`partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort): gives you the top elements, sorted

This wastes less watts on your CPU, will contribute to overall desktop performance, and your laptop batteries last longer so can do even more sorts.

Comment: yes this i what i meant to do because i only need one of every word to show a top ten.

Comment: the `auto pred = [](wordFrequency const &lhs, wordFrequency const &rhs)` line of your code throws two errors one is C++ requires a type specifier for all specifications and the second is `Expected expression`

Comment: @bobthemac: See also "This problem", it's about top-ten :)

Comment: @bobthemac: Note that the code using `auto` is C++11 code. You can also write a functor.

Comment: I have tried using `partial_sort(words.begin(), words.begin()+10, words.end());` as shown on this website link but i get three `invalid operands to binary expression` errors.

Comment: i talked to a friend and managed to get it working thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The most probable answer is that `operator<` is not declared for the type of object vec contains. Have you overloaded it? It should look something like that:

```
bool operator<(const YourType& _a, const YourType& _b)
{
   //... comparison check here
}
```

Comment: I think what is really needed is operator<

Comment: @Rob: you guys are both right, I thought == because of the `std::unique` call, but obviously `operator==` is provided. I will correct.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work, as std::unique returns an iterator pointing to the beginning of the duplicate elements. What type is your vector containing? Perhaps you need to implement the equality operator.